# Recover files from GitHub Desktop history

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am in the middle of a failed push using GitHub Desktop.

I accidentally committed some large files, and when I pushed to GitHub a message returns saying it exceeded the 100 MB file limit.

In my attempt to fix this, the original files have been deleted from the repository. But I can still view them in the history section of GitHub Desktop.

[image: Example]

Is it possible to recover these files?

Comment: A failed push should not affect your local repo. The history should be unaffected you deleting the files in the folders.

Comment: The files are missing from the local repo, that is why I have a problem

Comment: Try checking out the master branch? Or any branch?

Comment: @evolutionxbox how do you do that?

Comment: Not sure. I don’t use the github desktop gui, if it’s like sourcetree you either double click a branch name or right click and select “checkout”